# How to monitor the percentage of specfic turtles dependent on a turtles-own variable?

Tags: netlogo, percentage, monitor, agent-based-modeling

I would like to add a monitor on my interface which shows the amount of firms-at-home (in %) of all firms in the setup-world.

I'm trying to set up firms (turtles) in an industry (world) which either produce at home (firms-at-home) or have offshored their production (offshore-firms). I have given them a firms-own called offshored? which is answered with either true or false.

I tried this code:

```
breed [ firms firm ]

firms-own [
  offshored?   ;; true or false
  reshored?   ;; true or false
]

to-report offshored-firms
  report 100 * [ if firms with offshored? true ] / n-of firms ]
end

to-report firms-at-home
  report 100 * [ if firms with offshored? false ] / n-of firms ]
end
```

Then I would put `firms-at-home` in the reporter window of my monitor.

I'm not dividing the number of `offshored-firms` or `firms-at-home` by the total number of `firms` because I just cannot figure out how. 
Thanks for your input!

Comment: I think you're looking for `count`. try replacing `[ if firms with offshore? true]` with `count firms with [offshore?]`

Comment: Thank you! It worked like this: `report ( ( count firms with [ offshore? = true ] ) / count firms ) * 100`. But now it gives me a decimal number. Is there a way of having NetLogo report a number without the decimals?

Comment: `round`, `precision`, `floor`, `ceiling`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.